# Where to buy Bitcoin with Paypal?

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins, paypal

I have a Paypal account and I don't want to give up my ID card. Where could I buy Bitcoin at a price reasonably close to the exchange rate?

Comment: Generally people will not want to be paid through Paypal as it reveals their address to the purchaser. That is why people use exchanges.

Comment: But is there exchanges that allow to use Paypal ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to buy in dollars then you can do exactly this through irc channel [#bitcoin-otc](https://bitcoin-otc.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are several Bitcoin sellers on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/) that will accept payment by Payal.